# calling agent send dialog box to user xpages

Tags: dialog, xpages, send, agent

how to send error message to user from agent when using xpages?

Here the detail engine:
1. The xpages contains a button. when the button was clicked then it will call the agent to process the context info
2. On processing the agent, is it possible to send warning message to user (dialog box)? If yes, What command for send it?

Thanks

Comment: how do you call the agent?

Answer (score 2):

An agent cannot directly interact with XPages. One method would be to write output to a control document and for XPages to pick up that control document and put the message in a requestScope variable to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul. Just adding a small snippet here for you to start:

```
var agentName:String = "agentName";
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent(agentName);
if (agent != null) 
{
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument() // assuming datasource name is document1
agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc); 
/* 
In your agent you process a document with particular form and say a unique id of the passed 
document context 
*/
var v:NotesView = database.getView("warningView"); // For eg. stored in a warning view
var warningDocument:NotesDocument = v.getDocumentByKey(doc.getUniversalID());
// You can process the document according to your needs then ( you can do later step after your dialog is opened)
} 
else 
{
// throw and error message
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just info, my agent uses lotus script. Does your code able put in lotus script?

Comment: Just try to understand the code via the comments and write it down in lotusscript..

Answer (score 0):

Chintan and Paul are correct. Using the technique [described in this article](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH) you can capture all print output from an agent and use that in the XPage. However....

This is an excellent opportunity to pay down some technical debt and transform your agent into a bean. If it is well written, it should be easy. If its not, then you clean it up